# obj and fields should be of the same length, got 8 and 14

Tags: python, sql, databricks

In Databricks I'm trying to do this simple Count Statement but keep getting this error
This is the code

```
%sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
```

This this the error

```
    SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 259.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 259.0 (TID 442) (ip-10-172-229-228.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 1841, in main
        process()
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 1833, in process
        serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 357, in dump_stream
        vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 88, in wrapper
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1563, in prepare
        verify_func(obj)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 2397, in verify
        verify_value(obj)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 2360, in verify_struct
        raise PySparkValueError(
    pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkValueError: [LENGTH_SHOULD_BE_THE_SAME] obj and fields should be of the same length, got 8 and 14.
    
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:547)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:903)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:888)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:503)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:92)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:87)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:151)
        at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:145)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:942)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:945)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:837)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the statement

I wanted it to simply give me a count of every row in the table but I get this error instead